# predict function in Tree package

Tags: r

I have classification tree in R, I tried cross validation by:

```
cv.tree1<-cv.tree(tree1)
```

Then I  tried

```
tree3 = prune.tree(tree1, best=15)
```

Then I am trying to predict all my labels from the current tree:

```
predict(tree3, data.train[1,])
```

The output is:

```
            0         1          2          3           4           5           6          7          8
1 0.0006247397 0.8531862 0.03706789 0.02207414 0.003123698 0.008746356 0.009371095 0.00728863 0.05310287
            9
1 0.005414411
```

As I understand it gives me the probability of each label since I have 10 labels here 0:9
So I am trying to get max of last statement for prediction of all labels

```
predict.list <-matrix(0,nrow=nrow(data.train),ncol=10)
for (index in c(1:nrow(digits.train)))
{
  predict.list[index]<-predict(tree3, data.train[index,])
}
```

and then I tried to get max of each row in predict.list, but actually this doesn't work
So I tried to see the structure of 
str(predict(tree3, data.train[index,]))
I found it's

```
   num [1, 1:10] 0.00656 0.00583 0.00947 0.07479 0.14813 ...
  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr "8184"
  ..$ : chr [1:10] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
```

So the question is, Am I right in getting max. of each one so by that way I got the prediction, and how I can get the max with corresponding label

I can get the max by

```
max(predict(tree3, digits.train[1,]))
```

but I can't get the corresponding label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `predict.tree()` function has an argument called `type`. Its default value is `"vector"`, which in case of a classification tree will return a vector containing the class probabilities for each of your observation row. You can change it to `"class"` and it will only return the class with the highest probability. In your case using

> predict.list <- predict(tree3, data.train, type="class")

will return a factor vector of length `nrow(data.train)` with each value being the factor level that was predicted for the corresponding row.

Comment: Thanks it works, but I tried the loop to get all prediction and save it in a file, but it gives me more data than expected, Do you have any idea if it adds more data ?

Comment: You don't need to loop to get all the predictions for a dataset. If you don't specify a row it will return a vector containing all predictions for the dataset.